# add a column with connected groups based on two columns wthin another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

**tab1**

```
Group1 Group2 
G1     G2
G4     G3
G5     G3
```

**tab2**

```
Names           Groups
Canis_lupus     G1     
Cattus_cattus   G1
Mus_musculus    G1
Danio_rerio     G2
Betta_splendens G2
Griseus_gris    G3
Buffallo_kol    G3 
Homo_sapiens    G4
Macaque_ser     G4
Wistiti_del     G5 
Apis_mellifera  G6
```

And I would like to add a new `Connected_groups` column to the **tab2** where I put all connect groups within the **tab1**

I should then get :

```
Names           Groups   Connected_groups 
Canis_lupus     G1       G1-G2
Cattus_cattus   G1       G1-G2
Mus_musculus    G1       G1-G2
Danio_rerio     G2       G1-G2
Betta_splendens G2       G1-G2
Griseus_gris    G3       G3-G4-G5
Buffallo_kol    G3       G3-G4-G5
Homo_sapiens    G4       G3-G4-G5
Macaque_ser     G4       G3-G4-G5
Wistiti_del     G5       G3-G4-G5
Apis_mellifera  G6       G6
```

Here are the dic format of the df if it can helps ;

```
tab1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Group1': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G4', 2: 'G5'}, 'Group2': {0: 'G2', 1: 'G3', 2: 'G3'}})

tab2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Names': {0: 'Canis_lupus', 1: 'Cattus_cattus', 2: 'Mus_musculus', 3: 'Danio_rerio', 4: 'Betta_splendens', 5: 'Griseus_gris', 6: 'Buffallo_kol', 7: 'Homo_sapiens', 8: 'Macaque_ser', 9: 'Wistiti_del', 10: 'Apis_mellifera'}, 'Groups': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G1', 3: 'G2', 4: 'G2', 5: 'G3', 6: 'G3', 7: 'G4', 8: 'G4', 9: 'G5', 10: 'G6'}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `nextworkx` to find connected groups in `tab1`, then create a mapping dictionary of connected groups and use it with `replace` to substitute the values in `tab2`

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(tab1, 'Group1', 'Group2')
d = {k: '-'.join(c) for c in nx.connected_components(G) for k in c}

tab2['conn-grps'] = tab2['Groups'].replace(d)
```

---

```
              Names Groups conn-grps
0       Canis_lupus     G1     G2-G1
1     Cattus_cattus     G1     G2-G1
2      Mus_musculus     G1     G2-G1
3       Danio_rerio     G2     G2-G1
4   Betta_splendens     G2     G2-G1
5      Griseus_gris     G3  G3-G5-G4
6      Buffallo_kol     G3  G3-G5-G4
7      Homo_sapiens     G4  G3-G5-G4
8       Macaque_ser     G4  G3-G5-G4
9       Wistiti_del     G5  G3-G5-G4
10   Apis_mellifera     G6        G6
```